# Li element added from javascript not able to hide

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create  list item  and child list on each parent, and when the parent clicked the child need to be hide/show. Below is the code which works fine in the case of li element added as html.

```js
    function add() {
      var ul = document.getElementById("locations_id");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Element 4"));
      ul.appendChild(li);
       
    }
    
    function addLoc() {
      var loc = ["loc1","loc2","loc3"];
      var cam = ["cam1","cam2","cam3"];
    
      for(var i=0;i<loc.length;i++){
       var ul = document.getElementById("locations_id");
       var li = document.createElement("li");
       var a = document.createElement('a');
       a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(loc[i]));
       a.onclick = test(); 
       li.appendChild(a);
    
       var ul1 = document.createElement("ul");
       for(var j=0;j<cam.length;j++){
         var check = document.createElement("input");
         check.setAttribute('type','checkbox'); 
         check.setAttribute('name','cam'); 
         check.setAttribute('value',cam[j]);
         ul1.appendChild(check);
         ul1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cam[j]));  
         ul1.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));  
       }
        li.appendChild(ul1);
        
        
        ul.appendChild(li);
      }
      
       
    }
    function test() { alert('blah'); }
    
    $('.list > li a').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
        });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Test</title>
        
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
     <button onclick="addLoc()">Add </button> 
    
    
     <ul id="locations_id" class="list" style="list-style-type:none">
            <li>
                <a>Vehicle</a>
                <ul>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Bike<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" > Car<br>          
                </ul>                      
            </li>
        </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Where as the element I have added from javascript not seems show or hid when I click the parent item.

What could be the problem.

Comment: Just a heads up that `input` is not a valid child element of `ul`. Consider wrapping it inside an `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation. since you are creating li dynamically.

```
$(document).on('.list > li a','click',function() {
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Also

Add function name for onClick. It should not be

```
 a.onclick = test();
```

Use this

```
 a.onclick = test;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the listener is not attaching to the new li elements because they do not exist at the time that code is being run. Include the addition of the .click listener in the body of the addLoc() function, after the element has been added to the DOM.